# What's the difference between directory contents and directory entries?

Tags: bash, directory, filesystems, ls

The manpage for the `ls` command says that:

```
-d, --directorylist  
     directory entries instead of contents.
```

So, what's the difference between directory contents and entries? The `ls -d` command in my home directory only shows:

```
.
```

What's the purpose of the `-d` option of `ls` command?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the `-d` flag is most useful when you run `ls` with a wild card.

In a command such as `ls -l "B*"` if a directory is matched, then `ls` will list the contents of that directory. This is obnoxious if you don't care about the contents of the subdirectories.

For example, suppose your directory structure is as follows:

```
/tmp/Foo
    |-Bar
    |---FooBar
    |-Buzz
    |-FizzBuzz
```

`ls "/tmp/Foo/B*"` will produce the following:

```
/tmp/Foo/Buzz

/tmp/Foo/Bar:
Foobar
```

`ls -d "/tmp/Foo/B*"` will produce the following:

```
/tmp/Foo/Buzz
/tmp/Foo/Bar
```

Notice that the second case is almost certainly what was intended.

Answer (score 4):

If you do `ls -l`,  you will get the info for all the items ( contents) under (current) directory. But what if you wanted to see the info for the (current) directory? That is when you do `ls -ld`

Of course, since `ls` just prints the names of the contents, `ls -d` prints `.` ( or the directory name if given path) and seems useless.

You can also do `ls -d */` to list only the directories.

Answer (score 1):

```
-d, --directorylist  
     directory entries instead of contents.
```

It simply means that the whatever information/entries is available about the directory would be displayed (and not its contents).